# Factor $x^5-5x^3+4x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I am trying to factor$x^5-5x^3+4x$ so that I can find the roots. I know from the answers section that the roots are where $x = 0, 1, -1, 2$ and $-2$.

I'm stuck, here's as far as I got:

$$
x^5-5x^3+4x = 
x(x^4-5x^2+4)
$$

Let $u = x^2$ and just focus on the term on the right (drop the first $x$ for now):

$$x^4-5x^2+4 = u^2-5u+4x.$$

Master term is $a \times c = 1 \times 4 = 4$.

Seeking a pair of numbers that sum to the middle term $-5$ and whose product is $4$:

\begin{align}
1 \times -4 &= -4, &\text{sum} &= -3 \\
4 \times -1 &= -4, &\text{sum} &= 3 \\
2 \times -2 &= -4, &\text{sum} &= 0
\end{align}

???

I'm not sure how to proceed since I cannot find a pair of numbers that satisfy the condition.

Have I gone wrong somewhere? How can I factor $u^2-5u+4x$?

Comment: $$u^2 - 5u + 4 = (u-1)(u-4). $$

Comment: you are seeking a pair of numbers whose product is $4$, but your steps is finding a pair of numbers whose product is $-4$

Comment: $(-1)+(-4)=(-5)$ while $(-1)\times(-4)=(+4)$

Comment: Substituting $u=x^2$ into $x^4 - 5x^2 +4$ yields $u^2 - 5u + 4$, not $u^2 - 5u + 4x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$x^5-5x^3+4x=x(x^4-5x^2+4)$$$$=x(x^4-4x^2-x^2+4)$$$$=x(x^2(x^2-4)-(x^2-4))$$$$=x((x^2-4)(x^2-1))$$
$$=x(x+2)(x-2)(x+1)(x-1)$$

Answer (score 4):

You have to factor $u^2 - 5u+4$, not $u^2 - 5u +4x$. Since $1\cdot 4 = 4$ and $1+ 4 = 5$, $u^2-5u+4=(u-4)(u-1)=(x^2-4)(x^2-1)$